# How to select font with its style attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html mark up.

```
<p> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
<font style="background-color:yellow"> ipsum </font> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam id enim in tellus sollicitudin viverra. Morbi nec ipsum ligula, non volutpat enim. In quis metus <font style="color:red"> Tincidunt lorem </font>blandit faucibus. Nam condimentum facilisis vestibulum. Nunc tristique est vel erat sagittis ac placerat orci varius.</p>
```

I want to select only the font which has the "`background-color:yellow`" not any other `<font>` tag with any style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried that , but somehow addClass was not working.  so come up with this solution.

```
$('font').filter(function(){ 
            var bg=$(this).css("background-color"); 
            alert('bghlight - ' + bg);
       if ( bg == "rgb(255, 255, 0)" || bg == "yellow" )
       {
        $(this).addClass('hlight');
        $('font.hlight').each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith($('<abbr>' + this.innerHTML + '</abbr>').addClass('abbr-hlight'));  
        });
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use a filter function:

```
$("font").filter(function(){
    var bg=$(this).css("background-color");
    return bg=="yellow" || bg=="rgb(255,255,0)";
});
```

**UPDATE**

To add the class call the addClass function:

```
$("font").filter(function(){
    var bg=$(this).css("background-color");
    return bg=="yellow" || bg=="rgb(255,255,0)";
}).addClass("hlight");
```

Comment: ok I filter that, now how to add the Class to that FONT tag like wise 'hlight'.

Comment: Updated the answer hope it helps

Comment: thanks a lot .. please view my Answer for the code I have used.